# How to redirect one domain to another through ajax and python tornado?

Tags: python, ajax, tornado

I have a ajax call to one domain which is having a tornado server running,

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://test.example.com/setvalhandler",
      type:'POST',
      cache: false,
      data: {rsp:JSON.stringify(response)},
      success: function(resp) {
      },
      error: function() {

      }
  });
```

I have a tornado server which has "/setvalhandler" handler. I have set header for cross domain request. Finally i want to redirect to a different handler in tornado. But i am getting "302 Found" and "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" warning in browser console.

Python Code:

```
class SetvalHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def set_default_headers(self):       
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com/") # request origin domain
    def post(self):
        self.redirect("/newhadler")
```

Comment: sounds a lot like what's described in http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-protection

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sending the url that you need to redirect to as a response. Then redirect to the new page from the front-end by using window.redirect or something similar.

PS: It might be possible from the back-end as well. But I think redirecting from front-end is easier.

Comment: Thanks Swetabh. But for security reason intentionally i am trying from backend

Comment: What is the security consideration that you are specifically trying to address here?